# Get a date interval

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this excel formula that is doing a lookup and check if a specific day is considered as public holiday or not

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3;Sheet1!$Q$22:$R$35;2;FALSE);0)
```

**This is the final example**

[image]

The first column is checking if the date on column E is listed on the public holidays table and it formats it accordingly.
BTW S, F and FS is weekday, public holiday and weekend respctively.

**This is a portion of the table that has all public holidays listed**

[image]

Since the public holiday table only has 14 records (had to add some formulas to calculate all days as some of them don't fall on the same date every year) it's easy to keep track.
Let's say I want to automatically check the days I told excel I want to be considered as vacation. I can write the 1 by 1 but it's such a hassle.

So what I'm asking is if is there a formula on excel where I can tell it that from one date to another (Oct 20th to Nov 3rd) I want it to be considered as vacation? after that I'll do the formatting.

haven't tried anything yet

Comment: You dont need formula. Type the first date and then drag. Excel will fill with sequential dates, if this is what you need.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I know, trying to make it minimal, since I have other information on the sheet.if I wanted to take a 3 weeks vacation, I had to “write” a lot. That’s why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark a range of dates as vacation in Excel, you can use an `IF` and `AND` formula to check if the date in column E falls within the vacation period and return "Vacation" accordingly.

```
=IF(AND(E3 >= DATE(2023,10,20), E3 <= DATE(2023,11,3)), "Vacation", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3, Sheet1!$Q$22:$R$35, 2, FALSE), 0))
```

This formula first checks if the date in cell `E3` is within your vacation period (October 20, 2023, to November 3, 2023). If it is, the cell will display "Vacation". Otherwise, it will proceed with your original `VLOOKUP` for public holidays.

#### Comment Reply:

You can create a separate table for vacation periods and use a nested `IF` combined with `SUMPRODUCT` to look up if a date falls within any of those periods, and then label it as "Vacation".

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((E3 >= TableVacation[Start]) * (E3 <= TableVacation[End])), "Vacation", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3, Sheet1!$Q$22:$R$35, 2, FALSE), 0))
```

Here `TableVacation` is the name of the table that contains the vacation periods with columns `Start` and `End` for the date ranges. This formula checks if the date in `E3` falls within any of the ranges specified in `TableVacation`. If it does, it returns "Vacation"; otherwise, it performs the `VLOOKUP` for public holidays.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help.
I don’t want to sound ungrateful but can I create a table with all the dates (different periods and do a lookup?

Comment: Feel free to accept if it worked for you.

Comment: Edited my 1srt comment

Comment: Yes. See updated answer.

Comment: Marked as the best answer.
Thank you for your answer. Now I just have to find a way yo link the table column to another sheet. I have a specific "Helper" sheet where I keep all that extra info.
Once again, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Just add the Sheet name before the table name. For example: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT((E3 >= 'Sheet2'!TableVacation[Start]) * (E3 <= 'Sheet2'!TableVacation[End])), "Vacation", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3, Sheet1!$Q$22:$R$35, 2, FALSE), 0))
`